# Read a card number (EMV) with NFC and copy it to clipboard

Tags: android, nfc

I'm looking for an Android App which allows me to read credi/debit card number via NFC and copy this number to clipboard. It's for prevent typos when trying to fill a card number in hurry.

1. OS: Android (no root)
2. Reasonable requirement scope
3. Opensource (nice to have)

Is definetly possible to read it, for example [NFC Credit Card Reader (EMV)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pkfw.nfccreditcardreader) is able to do it, but it returns card properties as JSON only.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Never tried any such; but while waiting, you could have a look at my [list of NFC apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_nfc), some seem to work in that area (eg [Credit Card Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.devnied.emvnfccard)).